# Manually and conditionally load plugins for Vim

Tags: vim

I have two different projects that I'm working on (let's call them projA and projB) that have their own Vim plugins.

Each plugin folder has an ftdetect, ftplugin, plugin and syntax subfolder, and each deals with the same type of files (.cpp, .html, etc).

If I load both sets of plugins then nothing I want works right so I need a way to only load the plugin that corresponds to the project I'm working on.

My idea is to detect what my current working directory is via `getcwd()` and then only load the relevant plugin, but I have no idea how to manually load a single plugin.

I'm currently using Vundle to manage the rest of my plugins.

Comment: Why don't you just have conditionals and have Vundle load one of the plugin depending on these conditionals?

Comment: I'm very curious about the reasons behind your question and, for example, why you would want certain html ftplugins to be loaded in one project and another set in the other project. What do you want to fix? Performance issues? Conflicts?

Comment: Mostly because the projects are pretty massive and have thus spawned their own massive plugins. So the cpp syntax highlighting for example has lots of project specific stuff scattered through. So mostly conflict issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package managers like Vundle and Pathogen separate each plugin into its own subtree and concatenate all those paths into the `'runtimepath'` option so that Vim considers all of them. That makes it particularly simple to disable plugins: Just prevent the inclusion of the plugin's subtree into `'runtimepath'`.

Vundle references plugins in `~/.vimrc` via `Bundle 'foo/bar'` commands, so you just have to put a conditional around it:

```
if getcwd() ==# '/work/cpp'
    Bundle example/cpp
else
    Bundle example/other
endif
```

### conventional approach

With a conventional, single `~/.vim/` configuration hierarchy, you'd have to resort to suppressing plugin loads by setting the canonical `g:loaded_PluginName` inclusion guard. This requires support from the plugin, and mostly won't work for ftplugins, indent, and syntax scripts.

Answer (score 5):

## With [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)

The `vim-plug` plugin manager supports loading plugins conditionally.

This is straight from their readme:

```
" On-demand loading
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }
```